# Java: why am I able to compile passing unbounded generic as a bounded parameter?

Tags: java, generics, interface

I stumbled upon this issue with JavaFx, but it could be simplified to the following compilable launchable code. But shouldn't it fail *compile-time*? The only thing we can be sure about test2() is that it returns Object or null, it's <V(extends Object)>, not <V extends IDummy>. Why am I able to compile it?

```
public class Main {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test(test2());
    }
    
    private static void test(IDummy prop) {}
    
    private static <V> V test2(){
        return null;
    }
    
    public interface IDummy {}
}
```

Comment: That is odd, and I don't have an explanation.  Perhaps the generic type `<V>` is being picked up to assume `IDummy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<V> V test2()` says "this is a method that accepts an unbounded type parameter `V` and returns an object of that type".

Let's ignore for a second how the implementation of that would look like (we'll get to that later).

So if you call `test(test2())` the compiler knows that the result of `test2()` *should be* an `IDummy`. Is there a way to ensure that? Yes, there is: just pass `IDummy` as the concrete type parameter (`Main.<IDummy>test2()` would be the explicit way to write it, but the compiler infers that for you).

So the compiler knows that you want to use `IDummy` for `V` and automagically does it for you. Therefore the whole statement compiles.

Now let's go back to the issue of *implementing* `test2()` in a meaningful way. There's really only 2 possible ways to implement it:

- return `null` (because that's a valid value for every type that `V` could represent) *or*
- cheat by using an unchecked cast.

The second option would be something like writing

```
V value = (V) new Object(); // or any other value
return value;
```

This would compile with a warning. The warning basically means that the type guarantees by generics are broken by this.

*Sometimes* that can be useful when you know that the inferred type is *usually* correct (for example if you had `<V> V getProperty(String propertyName)`, then as long as every call had the correct propertyName/type combination it would actually work). But it's not strictly correct and you're basically asking the compiler to "trust me". Any breakage will result in runtime exceptions (most likely a `ClassCastException` eventually).

Comment: **The second option would be something like** 

Yep, my case exactly: wrapper over Map<String,javafx.beans.property.Property<?>> to also get values directly.

**So the compiler knows that you want to use IDummy for V** 

Thats where I expected request of the explicit cast instead of that behaviour. Accidently passed getValue() instead of getProperty().

So, *Type inference*. Got to read about it, thanks!

Comment: @Just_LeonS: yes, that sounds like the kind of use case. It's sometimes done, but you should keep in mind that you're sidestepping the real type-checking of generics and therefore can get unexpected ClassCastExceptions when it's used or implemented wrong.

Answer (score -5):

I think it's due to compiled type erasure.
Looking at the class file, the test2() method should return IDummy.
Finally, I recommend learning more knowledge about generics.

Comment: Please don't post comments as answers.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).